# How do I install grpcio on m1 Mac?

Tags: python, apple-silicon

Tried with Homebrew clang version 14.0.6, uninstalled it, tried with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5), but it doesn't compile.

I don't know much about compiling C when it's going wrong.

[output of `pip install grpcio`](https://gist.github.com/egigoka/272d7ab4233dae6885699b1ae9ab2d3b)

Comment: Hi! Is your pip 9.0.1 and python 3.5 already? https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/ using their virtual env quick start seems a good way to isolate things on macOS.

Comment: @bmike my pip version is 22.2.2 and python is 3.10. I've tried doing everything in venv, but errors are the same. Tried miniconda, different versions of grpcio, everything fails.

Comment: There is a similar question with up to date answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640705/how-can-i-install-grpcio-on-an-apple-m1-silicon-laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did google bunch of stuff, but didn't recognise the name of gRPC, lol. When googling with gRPC in mind, I found answer:

```
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68137855/6519078

Comment: Nice! Good answer to a question that will help others surely